# Undefined modules inside require() for requirejs

Tags: requirejs

Below are my codes

```
// config
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: 'library/jquery',
        jsBarcode: 'library/jsBarcode.all.min',                                                                                  
        q: 'library/q.min',
    },  
    shim: {
        jsBarcode: {
            deps: ['jquery'],
            export: 'JsBarcode',
        },  
    }   
});

// Main entry
require(['jquery', 'q', 'jsBarcode'], function (j, q, barcode) {
    window.Q = q;
    console.log(barcode); // get undefined
});
```

Directory layout

`└── webcontroller
        ├── bootstrap.min.css
        ├── image
        │   └── load_trans.gif
        ├── scripts
        │   ├── library
        │   │   ├── jquery.js
        │   │   ├── jsBarcode.all.min.js
        │   │   └── q.min.js
        │   ├── main.js
        │   ├── promise_factory.js
        │   ├── require.js
        │   └── view.js
        └── style.css`

- Loading sequences

The order for loading scripts is under my expectations.

[image]

- Problems

However, `barcode` is undefined all the time.

Any one have ideas about this problem?

- Updated

However, below codes can dump something out....

`console.log(JsBarcode);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix the typo `export` -> `exports`, it must be the root cause. Also you have three excessive commas although it seems not to cause troubles. Finally there must be some global `JsBarcode` defined in `jsBarcode.all.min.js` that's why your `console.log` dumps it.

```
    jsBarcode: {
        deps: ['jquery'],
        exports: 'JsBarcode'
    }
```